# Is it possible to create the dashboard in gcp to monitor the disk snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have customer environment where i need to create the dashboard to check and monitor snapshots created to my disks failure and success of snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

The only dashboard you can create in GCP are [Stackdriver dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/dashboards#configuring_dashboards) which are used to monitor [metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) of your project resources but not operations.

[GCE API - zoneOperations.get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zoneOperations/get) could be used to monitor the status of ongoing operation (create a snapshot in your case) and you can use this API in your scripting to monitor disk snapshot status. [This python-guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#operations) might help you to code for "waiting for operations".

These documentations from GitHub[1](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) might help further.

https://github.com/emind-systems/GCE-Disk-Snapshot/blob/master/gce-disk-snapshot.py
https://gist.github.com/tsabat/5890733